# Is there a way to prevent parallel::mclapply() accessing the contents of the global environment?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rscript, mclapply

Can the R function `parallel::mclapply()` be made to run in a RAM-efficient way in interactive RStudio sessions in situations where large objects reside in the global environment?

I find that when I use `mclapply()` to run analyses on multiple cores, the RAM consumed is always *substantially* (tens of GB, in my case) higher when running in an interactive RStudio session than when I run the exact same code via Rscript. My hunch is that this is because `mclapply()` duplicates the global environment on each core (I often have objects tens of gigabytes in size residing in the global environment), and supplying only the essential objects to the Rscript minimises this overhead.

I am using Linux AWS EC2 machines with large amounts of RAM (e.g., 64 GB to 128 GB) and reasonably large numbers of CPU cores (e.g., 16–32), and I often find that running `mclapply` on `detectCores() - 1` interactively maxes out the RAM almost instantly (increasing by many tens of GB in seconds), whereas running the exact same code via Rscript uses barely any more RAM than was consumed before `mclapply()` was called. I have observed this behaviour for a wide range of unrelated analyses --- hence the fact that I'm not including a reproducible example.

To run the `mclapply` call via Rscript, I first save the necessary data objects to an `.rda` file, and then use `system()` to run a script via Rscript that loads the data objects, runs the `mclapply()` call, and then saves the output to a file that can be loaded back into the interactive session.

Is this a widely-known problem? If the problem *is* because of `mclapply` copying the global environment on each core, is there a way to ensure that it can only access the variables necessary for the analysis?

Comment: Are you providing mclapply an index of a dataframe and then the mclapply function does the indexing of the data object or are you providing the dataobject as the main object for mclapply to iterate on. I suspect converting a big dataframe into a list of rows would be more memory efficient since if you provide the index for indexing then each R process will require the df to fulfil it's operation. Whereas if you have a list of rows (for example), each row should be processed once.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter. I've tried both passing individual rows and using indices/names to subset a single larger object, and I find that running mclapply in interactive RStudio sessions consistently use loads more RAM than in Rscript.